# How I can calculate index bond market

Tags: finance, bond, index

I know that some of the bonds on the market have been manipulated by investment funds.
I could identify these bonds.
I have classified similar bonds in terms of risk, maturity and Duration.
I have calculated YTM for all bonds.
Next, I would like to estimate their real value these bonds using the bond index.
My problem is I don't know how to make an index for each category and calculate the YTM index.
To understand more accurately:
My papers are divided into 30 categories according to the features.
And, for example, in the first batch there are 2 manipulated bonds and 25 similar ones and not manipulated. I want to make index using 25 bonds' YTM that could represent these value these 2 bonds. But I don't know how to make this index better?
i have 25 bonds. i calculate YTM for each them. now i don't know how i can make a index for in 25 bonds.

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: i have 25 bonds. i calculate YTM for each them. now i don't know how i can make a index for in 25 bonds.

Comment: You could weigh them by amount outstanding in a single currency. The sum would give you your index yield (to worst ideally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the average YTM of the index, you need to use the duration-adjusted market value weight ($mv_{wd}$) for any bond $i$:

$$mv_{wd;i} = \frac{mv_i \cdot d_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n mv_i \cdot d_i}$$

, where $d_i$ denotes the duration of a bond $i$ and $mv_i$ the market value.

The average index YTM, $Ind_{YTM}$, is than calculated by:

$$Ind_{YTM} = \sum_{i = 1}^n mv_{wd;i} \cdot YTM_i$$